# Obtener el valor de un documento en mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Tengo una colección en donde los documentos son como este (en MongoDB):

```
{
_id: 'ABPS1001',
Marca: 'DecNag',
serial: '2393-829-109',
resumen: [
    {
        estado: '1',
        nombresAg: 'Gina',
        apellidosAg: 'Saenz',
        coordinador_id: '1025',
        fechaMov: '25-10-2016 11:33'
    },
    {
        estado: '0',
        tecnicoID: '11',
        coordinador_id: '1025',
        fechaMov: '30-10-2016 16:29',
        idReemplazo: 'ABPS1026'
    },
    {
        estado: '1',
        nombresAg: 'Diana',
        apellidosAg: 'Gutierrez'
        coordinador_id: '1014',
        tecnico: '10',
        fechaMov: '04-11-2016 09:12'
    },
    {
        estado: '0',
        tecnicoID: '12',
        coordinador_id: '1014',
        fechaMov: '30-11-2016 16:25',
        idReemplazo: 'ABPS1021'
    },
    {
        estado: '1',
        nombresAg: 'Laura',
        apellidosAg: 'Diaz',
        coordinador_id: '1012',
        tecnico: '11',
        fechaMov: '04-12-2016 11:33'
    },
    {
        estado: '0',
        tecnicoID: '10',
        coordinador_id: '1012',
        fechaMov: '22-12-2016 12:21'
    },
    {
        estado: '1',
        nombresAg: '172.27.48.125',
        apellidosAg: ''
        coordinador_id: '1004',
        tecnico: '12',
        fechaMov: '27-12-2016 08:30',
        idReemplazo: 'ABPS1035'
    },
    {
        estado: '0',
        tecnicoID: '11',
        coordinador_id: '1004',
        fechaMov: '02-02-2017 14:12'
    }
 ]
 }
```

Necesito obtener la última entrada de "resumen" del documento con _id: 'ABPS1001' y no todo el objeto. Hay alguna manera de realizarlo con las sentencias de MongoDB en lugar de procesarlo con el lenguaje de programación?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Según la [documentación oficial](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-specified-fields-only), adaptado a tu caso:

`db.nombre_coleccion.find( { _id: "ABPS1001" }, { resumen: 1} )`

Si no deseas el campo `_id`:

`db.nombre_coleccion.find( { _id: "ABPS1001" }, { resumen: 1, _id: 0 } )`

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser con $[slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/update/slice/). Tu query puede ser así:

`db.collection.find({_id: "ABPS1001"}, {resumen: {$slice: -1}}).pretty()`

El resultado trae solo el último elemento del arreglo.